# Can I use barrier rectifier as a diode in bulk converter circuit?

Tags: diodes, filter, rectifier, passive-networks, low-pass

I have this LC circuit which will work under 12V and quite high load (10-20A):

[image]

The diode D1 must be a shottky diode but the only similar thing I have at the moment is actually 3-leg [MBR3045CT](http://www.diodes.com/_files/datasheets/MBR(F)3045CT.pdf) rectifier.

Can I use it as D1 diode visible in the circuit? 
Can I connect legs 1 and 3 together to serve as an anode and leg 2 as a cathode? IS this good idea and will it double max amperage it can handle?

Comment: What load current are you expecting?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include basic power supply information, It is intended to work with 12V and under 10-20A load.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that should work. And at your desired currents you will need to since each diode is rated up to only 15A.

And don't forget the heat sink; the package will be dissipating at least 4.2W at 10A.